How to run a Groupby and selection conditional variables in Hive?
I'm looking to select a conditional based on the following:
SELECT income_decile, income, benefits, 
COUNT(*) FROM income_dataset WHERE income > 50000 AND benefits < 2000; 
GROUP BY income_decile;

How do I run the groupie that sums each category as a pivot table does?

I t is very unclear what you are looking for and shiw what result you wat  from a given source data

To achieve a groupby and conditional selection in Hive, you need to be ensure the query's structured,
Here is the way you can do it,
SELECT 
    income_decile, 
    SUM(income) AS total_income, 
    SUM(benefits) AS total_benefits, 
    COUNT(*) AS total_count
FROM 
    income_dataset 
WHERE 
    income > 50000 
    AND benefits < 2000 
GROUP BY 
    income_decile;

